# Regex - Find a specific word and echo a line from results

Tags: php, regex

I had a problem with my code.

I am using Curl to fetch an html page and convert result to txt ..  then try to use preg_match to find a word in the txt results to be printed.

```
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL,$URL);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 30);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER,1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPAUTH, CURLAUTH_ANY);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_USERPWD, "$Us:$Ps");
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CONNECTTIMEOUT,2);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,2);
            $result=curl_exec ($ch);
            $status_code = curl_getinfo($ch, CURLINFO_HTTP_CODE);
            curl_close ($ch);
            $result= strip_tags($result);
            $pattern = preg_quote("connected", '/');
            $pattern = "/^.*$pattern.*\$/m";
            $final=preg_match_all($pattern, $result, $matches);
            $onn=strpos($result,"connected");
            echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);
```

the results of the HTML file after curl with this code (result):

```
OK NOK All / OK / NOK / IGN CWRate CASCUSERS Exp. Date Action ttt1 connected192.168.1.104 
cccam (2.0.11-2892)
```

the results of echo matches:

```
echo implode("\n", $matches[0]);
```

Gives:

```
connected192.168.1.104
```

What is needed to be changed in my code to print the word that is before (connected) like this:

```
 ttt1 connected192.168.1.104
```

Any ideas what do I have to change in my code? I think the change will be in the preg_match statement.

Comment: `/^.*\b\w+\bconnected.*$/m`

Comment: How is that? can you write the full statement because I tried this inside preg_quote and I had blank page output

Comment: No errors found, I have error reporting active in my file and it usually logs it in a local file. Blank page in this case means no matches found due to the wrong regex pattern. Please recheck the pattern. I am trying this: pattern = "/^.*\b\w+\bconnected.*$/m";

Answer (score 0):

Just add match any word: `\b\w+\b` to your `connected`.

So final regex looks like this:

`/^.*\b(\w+\b\sconnected(?:\d{1,3}\.?){4}).*$/m`

[Test here](https://regex101.com/r/Mk6cOA/2)

---

Few insights:

1. No need to escape `connected` word as there is no special chars
2. `\$` literally means `$` character. To match end of line use not escaped `$`

Comment: Thanks for the answer, I have used this:                 $pattern = "/^.*\b(\w+\b\sconnected(?:\d{1,3}\.?){4}).*$/m";
and still showing blank page without errors logged.

Comment: 1. Turn on error reporting _and_ error showing. 2. Instead of `echo` use `var_dump`. 3. Take your input and regex to regex validation page from example and experiment there

Comment: I have php errors showing active there. and I am not that much in php, can you help me what is needed to change? i tried var_dump and I got this result: string(1) " " array(0) { }

Comment: Note: I am using PHP 5.6 .. not 7 .. is that an issue?

Comment: @BHappy No, it should not matter of PHP version here. So just take your output, take regex and check if it's working outside of PHP.

Comment: @BHappy Oh, I see why your `\$` is working. Use my regex, but use it in single quotes, not double. Double quotes parses `\b` into literal `b`

Comment: @BHappy Or if using double quotes, then double escape slashes: `preg_match("/^.*\\b(\\w+\\b\\sconnected(?:\\d{1,3}\\.?){4}).*\$/m")`

Comment: Neither with single or double quotes any results, blank page only. tried this: $pattern = ("/^.*\\b(\\w+\\b\\sconnected(?:\\d{1,3}\\.?){4}).*\$/m"); ..... and tried this: $pattern = '/^.*\b(\w+\b\sconnected(?:\d{1,3}\.?){4}).*$/m'; .. with the same statements shown in my code and I still gets nothing.. this is a screen of my code:  https://dso2.raed.net/files/code.png

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/233598/discussion-between-justinas-and-b-happy).

Answer (score 0):

After couple of hours of searching and with some help from other questions on Stackoverflow, I've been able to figure this out all by myself with a special preg_match pattern as follows:

```
$pattern = preg_quote("connected", '/');
$pattern = "/^[\w\s]+$pattern.*$/m";
```

This regex above will match the connected word, and find the previous space and full word and match them.

Sample of the results ( Exactly how I wanted ) :

```
 Action ttt1 connected192.168.1.104 ttt2 connected192.168.1.104 ttt3 
 connected192.168.1.104
```